# fetch all contacts from android device error

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

Am building an app with phonegap which starts a background service, and in the background service a method is called which fetches all the users contact in json format.

Here is the code am testing with which was gotten from:

```
  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-contacts-application-with-jquery-mobile-the-android-sdk-part-1--mobile-5727
```

Code Below:

```
    public static String getAllContactDisplaysJSON(ContentResolver contentResolver){
    // Obtain all ContactDisplay objects from database and sort them
    ArrayList<ContactDisplay> list = getAllContactDisplays(contentResolver);
    Collections.sort(list); 

    // Populate the data structure consisting of ContactList-ContactGroup-ContactDisplay objects
    // Start with initializing some variables
    ContactList contactList = new ContactList();
    String key = "";
    ArrayList<ContactDisplay> values = new ArrayList<ContactDisplay>();
    ContactGroup group = null;      
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    // Process the list ContactDisplay objects to construct the data structure 
    if(list != null && !list.isEmpty()){            
        for(ContactDisplay display:list){
            if(!display.getKey().equals(key)){
                if(values.size() > 0){
                    group = new ContactGroup();
                    group.setKey(key);
                    group.setValues(values);
                    contactList.getContacts().add(group);
                }
                key = display.getKey();
                values = new ArrayList<ContactDisplay>();                                       
            }
            values.add(display);
        }
        // Add the last group
        if(values.size() > 0){
            group = new ContactGroup();
            group.setKey(key);
            group.setValues(values);
            contactList.getContacts().add(group);
        }
    }else{
        return EMPTY_CONTACT_LIST;
    }

    // We have the data structure of ContactList-ContactGroup-ContactDisplay objects where 
    // contactList is the root level element. Write it to a JSON formatted string using
    // org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.
    try{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(writer, contactList);
    }catch(Exception e){
        return EMPTY_CONTACT_LIST;
    }
    return writer.toString();               
}
```

when called from another class like so :

```
    protected JSONObject initialiseLatestResult() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final String ContactData = ContactUtility.getAllContactDisplaysJSON(getContentResolver());
    return null;
}
```

I get the following error in logcat :

```
                            03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.mycontacts.MyService: java.lang.NullPointerException
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1966)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:117)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:996)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:90)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at com.mycontacts.NativeServices.SendPushMsg(NativeServices.java:68)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at com.mycontacts.MyService.initialiseLatestResult(MyService.java:63)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService.initialiseService(BackgroundService.java:299)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService.onCreate(BackgroundService.java:129)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1956)
          03-01 07:55:25.289: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  ... 10 more
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022): [Blue Error Handler] Make Debugging Report file for main
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.mycontacts.MyService: java.lang.NullPointerException
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1966)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:117)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:996)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:90)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at com.mycontacts.NativeServices.SendPushMsg(NativeServices.java:68)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at com.mycontacts.MyService.initialiseLatestResult(MyService.java:63)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService.initialiseService(BackgroundService.java:299)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService.onCreate(BackgroundService.java:129)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1956)
          03-01 07:55:25.299: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):  ... 10 more
          03-01 07:55:32.529: I/BackgroundService(11063): Service creating
          03-01 07:55:32.529: I/BackgroundService(11063): Initialising the service
          03-01 07:55:32.529: W/dalvikvm(11063): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4017f560)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.mycontacts.MyService: java.lang.NullPointerException
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1966)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:117)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:996)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:90)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at com.mycontacts.NativeServices.SendPushMsg(NativeServices.java:68)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at com.mycontacts.MyService.initialiseLatestResult(MyService.java:63)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService.initialiseService(BackgroundService.java:299)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService.onCreate(BackgroundService.java:129)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1956)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  ... 10 more
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063): [Blue Error Handler] Make Debugging Report file for main
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.mycontacts.MyService: java.lang.NullPointerException
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1966)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:117)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:996)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:90)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at com.mycontacts.NativeServices.SendPushMsg(NativeServices.java:68)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at com.mycontacts.MyService.initialiseLatestResult(MyService.java:63)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService.initialiseService(BackgroundService.java:299)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService.onCreate(BackgroundService.java:129)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1956)
          03-01 07:55:32.529: E/AndroidRuntime(11063):  ... 10 more
```

Am New to Android(Java) so i don't really understand what is happening

Comment: Post the FULL stacktrace to the error, you are leaving out some important bits.

Comment: I have posted the full stacktrace

Comment: You have an NPE @ at com.mycontacts.NativeServices.SendPushMsg(NativeServices.java:68)

Answer (score 1):

you can fetch your contact name and phone number through my code and if you want to fetch image then tell and you can save all data into object arraylist and can show into custom adapter

```
 try {
                    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, null, null, null);

                    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
    //you can define String name and phone number globally use
                        String name = phones
                                .getString(phones
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        Log.d("NAME", name);

                        String phoneNumber = phones
                                .getString(phones
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));


                        }


                    }
                    phones.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
```